# CSS:checked not working

Tags: css, checked

my  php

```
<div class="navbar-header">
<label for="toogle" id="toogle">&#9776;</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="toogle"/>
</div>



 <div class="topbar-main">
                <?php // ADD Feb 2, 2016 (April)
                if(!empty($_SESSION["my"]->statusSp))
                    echo menuUserSpesial();
                else  // END ADD 
                    echo menu();
                ?>
                <ul class="nav navbar navbar-top-links navbar-right mbn">
                    <li class="dropdown">
.............
```

and i use

```
#toogle:checked + .topbar-main {
    width: 100% ;
  }
```

and then i use the General sibling combinator

```
#toogle:checked ~.topbar-main{
      width:100%;
}
```

it still did not work 
please help me

Comment: First of all, the label and input tags both have the same id. Secondly you are using selectors incorrectly. I recommend you read about CSS selectors before moving on

Answer (score 0):

Adjacent sibling and general sigling selectors wont work in your case as `.topbar-main` and `#toggle` are not siblings. They are inside different parents. The sibling selectors will only work if the elements have a common parent.

```
<div class="navbar-header"> <!--This is Parent of #toggle-->
<label for="toogle" id="toogle">&#9776;</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="toogle"/>
</div>
```

This block is separate.

```
<div class="topbar-main">
                <?php // ADD Feb 2, 2016 (April)
                if(!empty($_SESSION["my"]->statusSp))
                    echo menuUserSpesial();
                else  // END ADD 
                    echo menu();
                ?>
                <ul class="nav navbar navbar-top-links navbar-right mbn">
                    <li class="dropdown">
.............
```

Both `#toggle` and `.topbar-main` must be in the same container. Only then the sibling selectors will work.

Also as mentioned in the comment. You have a duplicate `id`. ID must be unique. I suggest you go through https://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/